# Cryptic one-line inequality solution -- can you make sense of it?

Tags: inequality

The following is a snip from the book *Olympiads: A Mathematical Olympiad Approach*:

[image]

The obvious approach (for me) is to use the triangle inequality to get
$$|a|-|b| \leq |a-b|$$
$$|b|-|a| \leq |b-a| = |a-b|$$

And the desired can be achieved by combining the two.

However, the given solution seems to do this much more succinctly. I have looked at this cryptic solution several times, but each time I've come back to it, I've never been able to make sense of it. Any help?

Comment: Just one of those tricks that you need to convince yourself that are useful, then remember them for future problems you'll meet.

Comment: I'm quite certain that what you wrote is the intended solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same solution, just expressed slightly differently.  $|a| = |a-b+b| \le |a-b| + |b|$ says $|a|-|b| \le |a-b|$.  $|b|=|b-a+a|\le |b-a|+|a|$ says $|b|-|a|\le |b-a|$.